# Отличие Bundle (SavedInstanceState) от SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences, android-bundle

Разбирал для себя тему: как восстановить данные после сворачивания. Понял что нужно использовать `Bundle (SavedInstanceState)` или `SharedPreferences`.

Вот теперь мне интересно какой из них в каком случаев использовать? Какая между ними разница? Какой для чего предпочтительнее?

Спасибо благодарю!

Comment: разница между ними такая, что это два совершенно разных механизма для решения абсолютно разных задач - они не альтернативные решения и предпочтение им отдается исходя из решаемой задачи. Сравнивать их на совпадения\отличия абсолютно нелепое занятие, как сравнивать отличия между пароходом и тетрадкой в клеточку

Comment: Хорошо спасибо это ваше мнение, можно было привести пример почему не стоит ну вы предпочли место сатире благодарю и на том .Но все равно для меня вопрос актуален .Спасибо за отзывчивсть

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Bundle` и `SharedPreferences` – это две разные вещи.

Объекты класса `Bundle` в основном используются для сохранения состояния объекта **в процессе жизненного цикла** того или иного компонента android-приложения (например, активити или фрагмента).

`SharedPreferences` используется для сохранения каких-либо пар `ключ:значение` **для их долгосрочного хранения**. Основное предназначение `SharedPreferences` – сохранение настроек приложения.

Comment: АААААА понел понел !!!! спасибо!

Comment: вообще сам по себе `Bundle` просто некий универсальный контейнер для группировки разнотипных данных в одном объекте, то что он используется и для сохранения состояния, лишь одно из его применений - он используется в API везде, где требуется передача нескольких параметров неизвестного заранее типа